# How to Append a Column to a Dataframe which is inside a Dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

`dict = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day'])} this is my first dictionary. [dataframe_sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyHK5.png)[dict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS1LB.png)I'm working on a data task. I'm producing some anomaly scores and I'm assigning these scores to empty dictionaries. Also I have more than one dataframe in another dictionary. 
I want to append the new column that I've produced as a result of anomaly detection and I want to append this column to each dataframe in my dictionary. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.
belows are mine empty dictionaries

```
result_anomaly_clustering={}
result_hbos_scoring={}
result_mad_based_outlier={}

for key in list(df_dict):
result_anomaly_clustering[key]=anomaly_clustering(2,df_dict[key])
result_hbos_scoring[key]=hbos_scoring (0.05,5,df_dict[key])
result_mad_based_outlier[key]=mad_based_outlier(3.5,df_dict[key])
```

Above code is my anomaly algorithm functions that I'm calling

Comment: provide us with sample of your both dictionaries

Comment: I've added the general view of dictionary and also added a sample from one of the dataframes in the dictionary.

Comment: provide us with some minimal code sample as well you have produced. otherwise see my answer below. thanks

Comment: I've added a sample of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found that the main problem is because of indexing in the functions. When I fixed the indexing in the functions, the problem was solved. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
# sample dictionary with anomaly scores
anomalies = {1: 2, 2:8}

# sample dictionary with dataframes
data_frames = {1: pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [4,4]}), 2:pd.DataFrame(data={'b':[6,6,7]})}

# iterate over key, value pairs of the dictionary of dataframes 
# and create column score taken from anomalies dict by key 
# with key matching anomalies dict key.
for k,v in data_frames.items():
    v['score'] = anomalies[k]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!